# Как правильно использовать promise в моем случае?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Есть некоторый объем данных. От 1 до десятков тысяч записей. Есть REST API которое возвращает данные в кол-ве 100 штук. Нужно используя это API выгрузить всё.

Я так понял, что нужно использовать promise. Но, видимо, я делаю что-то не так...

Вот пример кода:

```
// Функция которую я вызываю для получения данных
var load = function(promise) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        promise.then(function() {
            if (data.content.length != 100) {
                resolve(promiseLoadData(gid, data));
            } else {
                load(promiseLoadData(gid, data));
                console.log(data.content.length != data.total.posts);
            }
        });
    });
};
...
load(promiseLoadData(gid, data)).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Данные получить ни как не удается. Либо все зависает, либо я получаю пустое значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так:

```
var records = [];

function getItems(deferred) {
    deferred = deferred || $q.defer();

    promiseLoadData(gid, data).then(function (response) {

        Array.prototype.push.apply(records, response.data); //Добавляем наши записи в массив

        if (response.data.length == 100) getItems(deferred); //Если количество записей равно 100 - получаем следующую порцию.
        else {
            //Получена последняя порция записей
            deferred.resolve();
        }

    }, deferred.reject);

    return deferred.promise;
}

getItems().then(function () {
    console.log('все записи успешно получены. Всего записей', records.length);
}, function () {
    //При получннии записей произошла ошибка
});
```